# Variable Multiple Criteria for Autofilter in VBA

Tags: vba, autofilter

I'm looking to use VBA autofilter to better sort my data as I work through it.  I have around a 1000 rows each with a unique number and I'd like to be able to filter that data to the ID numbers I need at that moment.  Basically, the autofilter code below does the job for those 5 specific entries, but is there a way of making that a more flexible?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$13:$Y$1045").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "1776", "1870", "2029", "2051", "2086"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I picture using something along the lines of:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$13:$Y$1045").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        TexBox2.Value, TextBox2.Value), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

but no joy.  I'm a bit of a newbie, so huge apologies if this is a huge waste of time.  Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean with *no joy*? Do you have those TextBoxes somewhere in you sheet? Have you noticed that you wrote `TexBox1` rather than `TextBox1`

Comment: Sorry - TexBox1 is just a typo here.  I have a userform with textboxes and a button i would click to bring this code into action.  When I try and run the code I get Runtime error '424' : object required.

Comment: Your code looks fine and works on my side, without textbox references. Make sure they are retrieved correctly by reading them to variables first.

Comment: Sorry brainac, could you elaborate on that please? *sorry*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be little more precise:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$13:$Y$1045").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
    UserForm1.TexBoxt1.Value, UserForm1.TextBox2.Value) _
    , Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

where UserForm1 is the name of your userform. Be sure that you did not unloaded it before running this piece of code (you may .Hide it and still have access to the controls).